# I cannot get hideSoftInputFromWindow working

Tags: android

I try to hide the soft keyboard once the search is complete but I don't find why it fails.

I create the search menu like below:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

    String[] mSubActionsTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sub_actions_array);

    MenuItem item = menu.add(0, R.id.search, 0, mSubActionsTitles[0]);
    searchMenuItem = item;
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    mSearchView = new SearchView(getActivity());
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setOnCloseListener(this);
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.label_tvGivePosition));
    item.setActionView(mSearchView);
}
```

When the text is entered, I start an `AsyncTask()` which performs an HTTP query.
Then, we the response is received, I call the delegate where I try to hide the keyboard:

```
public synchronized void sitesLoadingFinish(Integer result) {

    searchMenuItem.collapseActionView();
    View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
    view.clearFocus();
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

So `searchMenuItem.collapseActionView()` is well collapsed, no problem, but I cannot get the soft keyboard closed.

Comment: try checking first if your view is not null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
view .postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    keyboard.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view, 0);
  }
},50);
```

Comment: Good! I don't really like to trust on delays but it helps me to get working.

Comment: How and where to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the same SearchView object to hide your keyboard

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mSearchView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score -2):

// Try like this

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Comment: isn't it what I did?

Comment: You need to add a delay see my comment which is upvoted 6 times